# Why does my function work just at the beginning of its code?

Tags: r, function, web-scraping, screen-scraping

The problem I'm having here is that, apparently, the only lines of code that the function is executing is

```
library(rvest)
library(RCurl)
```

and
 `url <-paste("https://www.confaz.fazenda.gov.br/legislacao/boletim-do-icms/",estate,"/",year,month,sep="")` as you guys can see at the end of the code.

So I think that the function can't attach values to any of the variables. Can you guys tell me how I could solve this?

I know that I could see what is happening with more detail using debug, but I'm having difficulty with that too.

```
icms_data <- function(estate, year, month){



  # Creating a data frame
  icms<- data.frame(NULL)

  library(rvest)
  library(RCurl)



  #downloading the webpage with the arguments from the function(estate, year and month)
  url <-paste("https://www.confaz.fazenda.gov.br/legislacao/boletim-do-icms/",estate,"/",year,month,sep="")
  #ignore token validation
  options(RCurlOptions = 
            list(capath = system.file("CurlSSL", 
                                      "cacert.pem", 
                                      package = "RCurl"), 
                 ssl.verifypeer = FALSE))

  y1<-getURL(url) 
  y <- read_html(y1)


  a<- y %>%
    html_nodes("#formfield-form-widgets-icms_primario div") %>%
    html_text()
  if(all.equal(a,character(0))==TRUE)
  {
    a=0
  } else
  {
    a<-substr(a,4,100)
    a = type.convert(a, na.strings = "NA", as.is = F, dec = ",",numerals = "no.loss")
  }

  b<- y %>%
    html_nodes("#formfield-form-widgets-icms_secundario div") %>%
    html_text()
  if(all.equal(b,character(0))==TRUE)
  {
    b=0
  } else
  {
    b<-substr(b,4,100)
    b = type.convert(b, na.strings = "NA", as.is = F, dec = ",",numerals = "no.loss")
  }
  #puting the information scraped into the data frame
  df<-data.frame(estate,year,month,a,b)
  icms<-rbind(icms,df)
  print(paste(url))
}
```

---

```
 > icms_data("SP","2018", "01")
Loading required package: xml2
Loading required package: bitops
[1] "https://www.confaz.fazenda.gov.br/legislacao/boletim-do-icms/SP/201801"
```

Comment: Short comment unrelated to the question: It's good practice to name functions with verbs rather than nouns. Thus a better name for the function would be something like 'parse_icms_data'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, as your output contains the printed URL, it looks like the entire function body is executed.

Judging by the name of your function, I assume you want it to return the variable `icms`.

R is a functional programming language and as such functions return their last executed expression as their result.

You should thus put `icms` or `return(icms)` at the very end of your function:

```
icms_data <- function(...){

     <everything else you wrote>

     icms<-rbind(icms,df)
     print(paste(url))
     icms
     }
```

*Some more background info:* variable assignments that you do inside a function using `<-` or `=` are *local* variables to the function environment, meaning they will not be available outside of the function body. If you want these variables outside of the function you need to (a) return them as described above or (b) assign them to a different environment (for example set "global variables" using `<<-`). Option (b) should generally be avoided unless you know the implications of what you are doing in detail, as it can otherwise cause name conflicts that are very hard to debug.

Comment: I'll second @hdkrgr's recommendation *against* the use of `<<-`. It introduces scope "violations" into your code which can make it harder to troubleshoot when things do not work as desired. There are very rare times when I intentionally use it, but in general it is usually not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about the local variables. I used then return on the variables "a" and "b". But now, the function just returns the value of a, but not of b

Comment: If you need to return multiple values, you can put them into a list: `return(list(icms=icms, a=a, b=b))`. And then after calling `result = my_function(params)` get the individual variables using `result$a` and so on